# Concat byte values with a operator?

Tags: c#, unicode, byte

In PHP I can concat every value with each other with ' . ' operator.
Now I want to concat some byte values in c# like this:

```
$byteData = "\x00\x00" . "Soroush" . "\x20";
```

Is it posible in c#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    byte[] byteData = (new byte[]{0,0}).Concat(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("asas")).Concat(new byte[]{20}).ToArray();
```

Comment: This is really what I want. U made my day happy bor:x

Answer (score 1):

You can use operator `+`:

```
string string_variable = "great";
string test = "This is a " + string_variable + " test";
```

You can convert byte array to string:

`string value = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(byteArray)`

Or, for UTF-8 use

`string System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byte[])`

To convert a string back to a byte array:

`byte[] byteArray = Hex.decodeHex(str.toCharArray());`